# How could Jesus, as one man, suffer the death penalty of multiple people?

Tags: jesus, sin, sacrifice, adam, atonement

In Genesis 2:17 God tells Adam: ”but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat, for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die.”‬‬

Because of Adam’s sin this rebellious nature, the original sin got into all of his descendants. Although the sin nature in us is a result of Adam’s sin, we are all responsible for our individual sins.

As Jesus’ sacrifice is a substitution for us (2 Cor 5:21), how is Him dying as one man enough to atone the death penalties millions of people deserve. Why shouldn’t there be a need for millions of substitutionary deaths? I guess the answer is somehow tied to Romans 5:19: ”For as by the one man’s disobedience the many were made sinners, so by the one man’s obedience the many will be made righteous.“ But I can’t fully understand the logic behind this. I fully understand that Jesus’ death freed us from the power of the original sin, but not how it is a substitution for all the people.
‭‭
Leviticus 16 addresses the scapegoat in the Day of Atonement as something the whole sin of Israel is put upon, but I don’t know how to connect this with Adam.

Comment: @Dan Welcome to BH. Do read the tour [below, left] to see how this site works.

Comment: The answer undoubtedly lies in the matter of whom Jesus of Nazareth actually was. Who was he that his death _could_ (in the sight of almighty God) be sufficient to atone for multitudes ? Who was he that the _worth_ of his person was (in the sight of almighty God) sufficient ? It is _God's_ estimation that matters, not humanity's and not a legal apprehension. Good question. Up-voted +1. Welcome to SE-BH.

Answer (score 2):

Adam’s (and Eve’s) fall has an ontological dimension in that through this fall the power of sin and, that of its consequence - death, infected the human nature. Only the Father’s co-eternal Son having adopted human nature could live a life of not only pre-lapsarian Adam, that is to say, of Adam before his fall and intrusion of sin, but incomparably loftier life of a God who adopted human nature from the Virgin, without transmission of sin, for it was a supra-natural birth, without a sexual intercourse.

Thus, the “Second Adam”, Christ as man is incomparably, infinitely greater than even Adam before fall, for Adam was not perfect - far from it! - even before his fall, while Christ as man was and is perfect, for only He showed the perfection and fulfillment of human life by laying His life by death on the Cross.

Everybody who accepts Christ’s salvific presence in himself through act of faith, gets this presence in his essence in the mode of Christ’s activity in the entirety of his essence, not only cleansing him from the Adam’s sin and healing him from Adam’s wound, but farther than that, leading human nature to perfection nay to deification.

This inner activity of Christ in us, through which we can say as Paul, “not I live any more, but Christ lives in me” (Gal. 2:20), is in a more popular, less technically-theological language called “grace”.

That’s why, truthful are those theologians who assert that Logos’ incarnation would have happened even had not Adam fallen, for it was a desire of God to make man perfect and deify him, which would be impossible without the Incarnation of the Son/Logos of God.

Comment: +1. Good answer.

Comment: @Dottard Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jesus, the Word of God, was God (John 1:1).

> “**All things** came into being through Him, and without Him **not
> even one thing** came into being that has come into being. **In Him
> was LIFE**, and the life was the light of men” (John 1:3-4).

Jesus is the Source of all life. All life originated through Him.

> “For **all things** were created in Him, the things in the heavens,
> and the things on the earth, the visible and the invisible; whether
> thrones, or lordships, or rulers, or authorities, **all things** have
> been created through Him and for Him. And He is before all things, and
> **all things have subsisted in Him**” (Col 1:16-17).

> “And **the Life** was revealed, and we have seen, and we bear witness,
> and we announce to you **the everlasting Life** which was with the
> Father, and was revealed to us” (1 John 1:2).

No wonder, Jesus Himself declared:

> “I am the Resurrection and **the Life**” (John 11:25). “I am the Way,
> and the Truth, and **the Life**” (John 14:6).

Jesus, as the Source of all life, is Life Himself, the everlasting Life.

> “the Lord (Jesus) is the Spirit” (2 Cor 3:17).

Jesus said:

> “It is the Spirit that gives life” (John 6:63).

When we combine 2 Cor 3:17 and John 6:63, we learn that it is the Lord Jesus who gives life to us.

But science says that all of us human beings have only “chemical life” now.

**The Answer**

To answer your question, we need to understand from the above Scriptures that Jesus Christ as the Source of all life is **greater than** all the chemical lives of all human beings put together.

So His one death is more than enough to atone for all humanity.

Answer (score 0):

In Acts 10:43, Peter tells Cornelius that, "All the prophets testify about him (Jesus) that **everyone who believes in him receives forgiveness of sins through his name**”. Similarly, John 3:16 states that "For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that **whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life**."

The redemption of Jesus is not a simple substitution of one's death for another. Rather, it relies on faith in Him and obedience to His teachings. As Paul writes in 2 Corinthians 5:17, "Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, the new creation has come: The old has gone, the new is here!". This transformation requires a radical change in one's life and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In my interpretation, original sin is the deviation of children's genomes from the parental genome through random mutation, which I term the "tree of variability." This deviation introduces genetic variability, contrasting with the concept of cloning where offspring are identical. In the case of Adam, who was perfect, his children are thus imperfect due to this variability. The inequality of children, in the sense that they are not clones but genetically diverse, coupled with the finite surface of the Earth, inevitably leads to inborn rivalry among heirs. This is exemplified in the biblical account of Cain killing his brother Abel, among other conflicts that arose both before and after the Flood.

The divine response to these challenges appears to have involved a form of genetic selection, which can be seen as either divine sponsorship or a more severe act of genocide. This selection process was directed at refining the human "hardware," aiming to mold a population that aligns more closely with a divinely preferred genetic makeup. However, the coming of Jesus Christ marks a critical shift in this divine approach. By becoming human and offering himself as a sacrifice, Jesus, as God's firstborn, removes the conflict inherent in firstborn inheritance rights. His death signifies a move from a focus on limited physical inheritance, bound to the Earth's constraints, to an unlimited spiritual inheritance in the heavens.

Thus, in my interpretation, Jesus' death addresses the fundamental problems of mankind that arose from genetic variability and the limitations of earthly resources. These problems, which previously could only be resolved through the death of many, are overcome by Jesus' singular sacrifice. He shifts the focus from the limited "hardware" of human genetics to the unlimited "software" of spiritual inheritance, offering a new form of existence where conflicts arising from genetic variability are transcended. This transformation allows for a universal resolution to the challenges of genetic diversity and competition for limited resources.